# Search all rows for a specific data attribute. If exists, hide other rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table. Each row has a `data-date` attribute. If one of these rows has a value of "Training Day", I want to delete all the other rows from the table (hide them).

```
var table_a = $("table#day_1_ch_dis tbody tr").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data("date") == "Training Day";
});

if (table_a.length > 0) {
  $("table#day_1_ch_dis tbody tr:not([data-date='Training Day']").hide();
}
```

This code works so far. My only worry is whether it's as clean as it could be. I'm guessing not. What's the best way to have this coded?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need `filter()`

```
if ($("#day_1_ch_dis tr[data-date='Training Day']").length) {
  $("#day_1_ch_dis tr:not([data-date='Training Day'])").hide();
}
```

or using [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$("#day_1_ch_dis tr[data-date='Training Day']")
  .siblings(":not([data-date='Training Day'])")
  .hide()
```

Comment: Ha - couldn't see the wood through the trees - thanks